# Track what JavaScript is called when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am working with some HTML that was provided by a design company. Unfortunately, they have a habit of changing their code without notice, requiring that I update my code in the actual web app.

There is a link that changes the class value on one div and toggles the display value between block and none on another. I'll be darned if I can figure out what JavaScript is getting called to make these changes.

Is there a way (Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, etc.) to tell what is getting called that is changing these values, short of pulling down the complete source and going through it line-by-line?

Comment: In Chrome Dev tools: `Sources` -> `Event Listener Breakpoints` -> `Mouse` -> `click` .